# Parse Error com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Parse server giving me an i/o failure anytime I try to make any query.

I have tried using another server, checking my connection, using other hones, starting a new android project, but nothing seems to work.

```
public class StarterApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Database.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId("b8c0194c615939346333f498a40551ff16eb7952")
        .clientKey("a54b263385f0a91a75537686c7afec0a77e3d3c7")
        .server("http://35.188.72.145:80/parse/")
        .build()
    );
    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ExampleObject");
    object.put("myNumber", "123");
    object.put("myString", "rob");
    object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e == null) {
          Log.i("Parse_Result", "Successful!");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse_Result", "Failed: " + e.toString());
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Instead of logging successful, I got the i/o failure.

Comment: It does not seem to be a SDK problem, but a server problem. Try to run `curl -X GET http://35.188.72.145:80/parse/health` and check if your server is healthy. I tried here and I got no response. Maybe some firewall? I'd suggest you to first run parse server in a local machine (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#locally) to make sure that your Android app is working and then try to setup a remote server.

Comment: Hello, I am still getting the i/o failure error, even when running it with mogodb locally

Comment: Is `curl -X GET http://yourlocalserver/parse/health` working?

Comment: I am getting port timeout after waiting for 20 seconds

Comment: So you have something wrong with your server. Can you please share the command you are using to start the parse server in your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the internet connection (in your AndroidManifest) is enabled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried adding internet connection in the AndroidManifest, try uninstalling the app from emulator and run the app again. This worked for me, may or may not work for you.